# highcharts bubble won't load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use Highcharts Bubble as example from its official website and try to modified it using Framework CodeIgniter.
I run it in GoogleChrome and Firefox but not show anything.
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>STATISTIK</title>

</head>

<link href="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script src="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<style>
#content {
    position: relative;
}
#content img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="content">
</div>
<!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/css/CreativeCSS3AnimationMenus/css/demo.css" /-->
<script src="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/jquery/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/jquery/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://10.16.107.77/statistik/public/jquery/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Formasi Tenaga Kerja'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[97,36,1000]],
            name: 'Area Medan'
        }, {
            data: [[25,10,1000]],
            name: 'Area Lubuk Pakam'
        }, {
            data: [[47,47,1000]],
            name: 'Area Binjai'
        }, {
            data: [[75,80,1000]],
            name: 'Area Sibolga'
        }, {
            data: [[60,25,1000]],
            name: 'Area Rantau Prapat'
        }, {
            data: [[100,80,1000]],
            name: 'Area Padang Sidempuan'
        }, {
            data: [[80,55,1000]],
            name: 'Area Nias'
        }, {
            data: [[75,80,1000]],
            name: 'Area Pematang Siantar'
        }]

    });

});
</script></body>
</html>
```

Thnks for every reply.
regards

Comment: were you able to see any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle example showing the error?

Comment: Maybe its just me, but I don't see how PHP and CodeIgniter are relevant. I don't see any trace of either in the provided code.

Comment: Is the path correct to your JS files?

Comment: @anurupr. I find these error

TypeError: R is undefined
 

...boxplot=o(p.column,{fillColor:"#FFFFFF",lineWidth:1,medianWidth:2,states:{hover:...

highch...more.js (line 29)
uncaught exception: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17

It tells something about missing highcharts-more.js
The code above already load that script. But still blank.

Comment: @gpgekko. Because I use template for CodeIgniter.

Comment: @stsho89 That error actually tells you that there is a type error, which is commonly triggered when people are trying to use a type they have not included. In this case however, you can see the error is originating from the `highcharts-more.js` file. I took a look and the line it is struggling with seems to be this one: `drawTracker:R.drawTrackerPoint};`. Note how it says `R is undefined` in your error message. It seems it is still missing a component. Looking at the source file, it translates to `drawTracker: TrackerMixin.drawTrackerPoint`, so you need to find this `TrackerMixin` object.

Comment: @bhttoan. I've tried these code in JSFiddle but got no error

Comment: @PaoloCasciello. I've tried these code in JSFiddle but got no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try importing highcharts-more.js file.
Look at the working example here :
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sf32b/2/)

code: 
HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I've already importing that script from file that I've copied in my server as the code above. I don't think that's the main problem. Thnx for reply

Comment: please check the demo and change accordingly

Comment: Thnx. I've tried your solution and it's works. But the next question is can't I just copied the scripts into my server and try it locally. Why it have to be loaded from its official site?

Comment: It's because your server is giving ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Try out locally and then check it with server